# How to get timestamp of a date?

Tags: php

How do I convert different formatted dates in timestamp in php ? I have date in this `August 2nd, 2015` format and I need to conver it to timestamp so that I can make comparisons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/DateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo $test = strtotime("August 2nd, 2015");
echo date("Y-m-d",$test);
?>
```

So use **strtotime("August 2nd, 2015");**

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime()` can and *will* bite you if you use it with date formats that are unclear, eg: `11/10/12`.

Learn to love [`DateTime:createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and be explicit in your parsing formats.

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat("d/y/m", "11/10/12"));

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2010-12-11 10:02:42.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Vancouver"
}
```